# Facebook login with JavaScript SDK error: “This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings”

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, backendless

**Description:** I am developing ionic hybrid application with social logins(facebook,twitter and google+) using backendless. social logins are working in the desktop browser but not in real device. While debugging I got

**URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.**

These are screen shots[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1KDg.png)
[image]

**Problem:** While registering our application with facebook they will ask for OAuth Redirect URL.There I have mentioned https://api.backendless.com/,http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab.

Social logins are working properly in desktop.When I run  ionic application in android it will open backendless site with empty page, because for mobile also  we should give OAuth Redirect UrIs since it is API key how could we give  url for OAuth Redirect UrIs?

Please could anybody help me? I got struct since last 2 days..